# TextView with id and textIsSelectable="true" causes leaking of the Activity object

Tags: android, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, textview

it took me three days to narrow my problem with this memory leak and I can't find anyone else describing this issue anywhere. That's why I would like to ask if someone could confirm I haven't just missed something. I've also submitted a bug report but the reason I'm asking here on SO (besides letting others know) is that I would like you to let me know of other Views and their attributes causing such problems so I can avoid them.

My problem is as follows:

(1.) create a simple Android application (e.g. the SkeletonApp sample application)

(2.) add the following at the end of onCreate() to cause memory allocation:

```
Log.i(this.toString(), ">>> onCreate()");
auxList = new ArrayList<int[]>();
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  auxList.add(new int[250000]);
}
Log.i(this.toString(), "<<< onCreate()");
```

(3.) (optional - just for convenience) override the following methods:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
  Log.i(this.toString(), ">>> onDestroy()");
  super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
  Log.i(this.toString(), ">>> finalize() !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
  super.finalize();
}
```

(4.) run the application and rotate the screen several times (pressing left CTRL+F11) - everything should work for now

(5.) in the layout (skeleton_activity.xml) add:

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/textViewDebug"
  android:layout_width="30dp"
  android:layout_height="32dp"
  android:textIsSelectable="true"
/>
```

(6.) repeat point (4.) - the logCat reveals that the Activity is destroyed after rotation but never finalized causing OutOfMemory error after several rotations

(7.) removing the textIsSelectable attribute or setting it to false as well as removing the id attribute (even while keeping textIsSelectable="true") prevents the issue.

Thanks for you comments!

PS: I'm new here and have no rights to add new tags. Could someone with enough points add a "textisselectable" tag to this question? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got an answer to my bug report stating that it can't be reproduced with the newest version of Android (I tested it on two devices running ICS). So I guess I'll just have to believe them as I don't have any newer device and it doesn't seem to bother anyone anyway. It's just a memory leak after all... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Check the Android Docs for use cases with finalize.  Finalize is expensive, and is probably what is causing your memory leak, not the value on your text field.

[Android Object](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html)

> Note that objects that override finalize are significantly more expensive than objects that don't. Finalizers may be run a long time after the object is no longer reachable, depending on memory pressure, so it's a bad idea to rely on them for cleanup. Note also that finalizers are run on a single VM-wide finalizer thread, so doing blocking work in a finalizer is a bad idea. A finalizer is usually only necessary for a class that has a native peer and needs to call a native method to destroy that peer. Even then, it's better to provide an explicit close method (and implement Closeable), and insist that callers manually dispose of instances. This works well for something like files, but less well for something like a BigInteger where typical calling code would have to deal with lots of temporaries. Unfortunately, code that creates lots of temporaries is the worst kind of code from the point of view of the single finalizer thread.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, I normally don't use finalize() at all. I had a memory leak in the first place and started using finalize() only to narrow my problem. That's why I marked point (3.) as optional/convenience because it just illustrates the issue nicely but the OutOfMemory errors appear even without using finalize() at all. I should have mentioned that in my question more obviously.